# Is there a module of finite type but not quasi-coherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme, could you construct a sheaf of module that is of finite type but not quasi-coherent? I want to let $X=Spec R$ where $R$ is a DVR. But I don't know how to construct such a module over it...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @KReiser I just want to learn a counterexample...

Comment: Well, have you tried the [standard example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/314386/does-every-sheaf-embed-into-a-quasicoherent-sheaf) of a non-quasi-coherent sheaf on a DVR?

Comment: @KReiser Ah! That's a good example! Thanks.